# Make SQL query parametrized to avoid SQL injection in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this code in which I am trying to parametrize my SQL query, but I am not quite sure whether it will work. I can't test the code at my environment right now.

Original code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsMrgnGroups.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    sqlQuery += "LTRIM(TO_CHAR(MAX(DECODE(CMD_MGG_ID, " + row["MG_GROUP_ID"] + " , CMD_MRGN_ORG_VALUE)), '999999999999999990.99')) AS Original,";
}

foreach (DataRow row in dsMrgnGroups.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    sqlQuery += "LTRIM(TO_CHAR(MAX(DECODE(CMD_MGG_ID, " + row["MG_GROUP_ID"] + " , CMD_MRGN_UPD_VALUE)), '999999999999999990.99')) AS MemUploaded,";
}
```

Code after parametrizing:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsMrgnGroups.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    sqlQuery += "LTRIM(TO_CHAR(MAX(DECODE(CMD_MGG_ID,:MG_GROUP_ID , CMD_MRGN_ORG_VALUE)), '999999999999999990.99')) AS Shorfall,";

    paramlist = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    paramlist.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MG_GROUP_ID", row["MG_GROUP_ID"].ToString()));

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(_connString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in paramlist)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _messageObj.WriteLog("Exception: DLL ->UpdateMarginsDLL -> GetMarginDetailsCM: " + ex.Message, _tmid, 1);
    }
}

foreach (DataRow row in dsMrgnGroups.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    sqlQuery += "LTRIM(TO_CHAR(MAX(DECODE(CMD_MGG_ID,:MG_GROUP_ID , CMD_MRGN_UPD_VALUE)), '999999999999999990.99')) AS Shorfall,";

    paramlist = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    paramlist.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MG_GROUP_ID", row["MG_GROUP_ID"].ToString()));

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(_connString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in paramlist)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _messageObj.WriteLog("Exception: DLL ->UpdateMarginsDLL -> GetMarginDetailsCM: " + ex.Message, _tmid, 1);
    }
}
```

But I think it will not serve the purpose of `sqlQuery+=` or won't work like `sqlQuery+=`. Also there are cases where I need to return query from a function after being parametrized. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Even if you are not sure you should try and run and then see if there’s any issues. You can put the breakpoint and see what query is it generating and run that directly into the database.

Comment: @viveknuna sorry I forgot to add . I can't test it at my environment as I do not have access to db at the moment .

Comment: "I can't test the code at my environment right now." - honestly, that sounds like the first and only thing to fix here. We aren't going to try psychic debugging. On a performance note: string concatenation is *relatively* expensive - if this is high volume, maybe use `StringBuilder`. Also, avoid `AddWithValue` generally - preferring manual add. Maybe consider Dapper or an ORM to remove some cruft. It looks like you might get multiple Shorfall columns. Not sure how that works.

Comment: move the whole mess to a single t-sql store procedure, and pass the parameters. This will also force you to write clean sql, and avoid conctenations. It will ALSO remove the messy sql that you building in code.